# Can I pass an if statement in the following code? If not is there an alternative?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<%#String.Format("~/storefront.aspx?CatalogID={0}&ProductID={1}", Eval("CatalogID"), Eval("ProductID"))%>
```

what I am trying to do is:

```
 NavigateUrl='<%#String.Format("~/storefront.aspx?CatalogID={0}&ProductID={1}",Eval("CatalogID"), (Eval("CatalogID")=="856" ? Eval("ProductID") : Eval("CustItem")))%>
```

I'm trying to link back to the item from a page.. and I have accomplished this for every item except the ones in catalogid 856 ...the url looks like: storefront.aspx?CatalogID=856&ProductID=AVE05418 that example is of one from catalog 856, problem is, is the productid being passed in the url is actually the a variable called CustItem so Im trying to pass the CustItem in the place of ProductID when the catalog is 856

Thank you

Comment: I'd fix it at the database layer.  The data is just plain wrong.  If you *have* to hack around it, hack around it inside the web application, not in any way that is visible outside the server (e.g. a web service interface or URL).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
Eval("CatalogID") == 856 ? Eval("CustItem") : Eval("ProductID")
```

**EDIT**

```
NavigateUrl='<%#String.Format("~/storefront.aspx?CatalogID={0}&ProductID={1}",Eval("CatalogID"), (Eval("CatalogID").ToString() == "856" ? Eval("CustItem") : Eval("ProductID")))%>'
```

Comment: @Joe W: If you can expand on how this will pertain to the link you're building, I will edit my answer to be more specific.

Comment: ok.. I'm trying to link back to the item from a page.. and I have accomplished this for every item except the ones in catalogid 856 ...the url looks like: storefront.aspx?CatalogID=856&ProductID=AVE05418 that example is of one from catalog 856, problem is, is the productid being passed in the url is actually the a variable called CustItem so Im trying to pass the CustItem in the place of ProductID when the catalog is 856, I hope that explains it a little better..

Comment: alright I found something I was missing which got just a little bit closer to wrapping this up, I was missing a ) .. so now i have:  NavigateUrl='<%#String.Format("~/storefront.aspx?CatalogID={0}&ProductID={1}",Eval("CatalogID"), (Eval("CatalogID")=="856" ? Eval("ProductID") : Eval("CustItem")))%> ... but its not doing the test, its going with which ever is first as in this segment I have Eval("ProductID") : Eval("CustItem") ...and it uses ProductID regardless, but if i switch them around it uses CustItem regardless.. any suggestions there?

Comment: @Joe W: To doing Eval("CatalogID").ToString() == "856" or Convert.ToInt32(Eval("CatalogID")) == 856.

Comment: Haha the little things you over look! Thank you yet again James!

Comment: @Joe W: Oh wait, you've got it backwards I think. The first value after the ? is the true condition. The value after the : is the false condition.

Comment: Yep I got it switched around and it works, I think you have been the biggest help for me on here to get things done fast haha not enough thanks

Comment: @Joe W: No worries. I await your next question with bated breath :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

```
Eval((CatalogID==856) ? "CustItem" : "ProductID")
```

Way better than that would be fixing the bad data that's found its way into your database so you could avoid this ugliness in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

> can anyone suggest how to deal with the given situation?

I'd fix it at the database layer. The data is just plain wrong.

If you have to hack around it, do not change the anything that is visible outside the server (e.g. a web service interface or URL).  Otherwise someone could take advantage of your work-around to subvert your data.

Allowing an `Eval` in your URL is just begging for problems.